# How to read `hadoop dfsadmin -report` output

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

Command:

`[hdfs@sandbox oozie]$ hadoop dfsadmin -report|head -n 100`

Output:

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Configured Capacity: 44716605440 (41.65 GB)
Present Capacity: 31614091245 (29.44 GB)
DFS Remaining: 30519073792 (28.42 GB)
DFS Used: 1095017453 (1.02 GB)
DFS Used%: 3.46%
Under replicated blocks: 657
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 10.0.2.15:50010 (sandbox.hortonworks.com)
Hostname: sandbox.hortonworks.com
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 44716605440 (41.65 GB)
DFS Used: 1095017453 (1.02 GB)
Non DFS Used: 13102514195 (12.20 GB)
DFS Remaining: 30519073792 (28.42 GB)
DFS Used%: 2.45%
DFS Remaining%: 68.25%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 4
Last contact: Thu Aug 11 23:12:04 UTC 2016
```

What is Cache Used%, Non DFS Used specially???

Answer (score 1):

`hdfs dfsadmin -report` command:

> Reports basic filesystem information and statistics. Optional flags
>   may be used to filter the list of displayed DataNodes.

..from official [page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin) of hadoop

About,

1. Cache Used%:

It depends on "Configured Cache Capacity". It's the percentage of the configured value. As you have not configured any space for cache, it is shown as 100% (0 B out of 0 B)

2. NonDFS used:

It is calculated using following formula

`NonDFS used = Configured Capacity - DFS Used - DFS Remaining`

Comment: request to explain more on Cache Used%:
How can we configure it and how to increase or decrease it.

How do we calculate "Configured capacity" ??

Comment: I have downloaded a dfs report file which looks similar. Now I need to upload these data to table, Any idea what is the easiest way to read them and upload data to table?